# Can't implement JavaScript flip counter

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I want to implement javascript flip counter. I included all needed files and added code as in this article - http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/#demo.

I added html in my page:

```
<div id="counter" class="flip-counter"></div>
```

and added javscript to my application.js:

```
  var myCounter = new flipCounter("counter", {inc: 23, pace: 500});
```

here is my included files(js and css):

```
      <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="/assets/counter.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
      <link href="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/assets/jquery-flipcounter.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"> </script>
      <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I will also write here what files demo page is including:

```
     <!-- My flip counter script, REQUIRED -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flipcounter.js"></script>
<!-- Style sheet for the counter, REQUIRED -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/counter.css" />
<!-- NOT REQUIRED FOR COUNTER TO FUNCTION, JUST FOR DEMO PURPOSES -->
<!-- jQuery from Google CDN, NOT REQUIRED for the counter itself -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQueryUI from Google CDN, used only for the fancy demo controls, NOT REQUIRED for the counter itself -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Style sheet for the jQueryUI controls, NOT REQUIRED for the counter itself -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- Style sheet for the demo page, NOT REQUIRED for the counter itself -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
```

and here is rar archive with working counter: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/cnanney-apple-style-flip-counter-13fd00129a41.rar.

Comment: do you get any errors in `console.log` ?

Comment: it's hard to tell where you are wrong since there is no actual code here. Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: I created fully empty html page in demo folder. Added files that are needed and get these errors in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input test.html:77
GET file://platform.linkedin.com/in.js  test.html:14`

Comment: then you have another problem .. something related with another js library

Comment: That was mine error. I fixed it and get new - `TypeError: div is null
div.insertBefore(newDigit, div.firstChild);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your `application.js`

```
$(function(){
    var myCounter = new flipCounter("counter", {inc: 23, pace: 500});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks like it should work.

Try adding you JavaScript inside a self anonymous invoking function.

```
$(function(){
    var myCounter = new flipCounter("counter", { inc:123, pace:600});
});
```

Also make sure all your included files point to the right location.

Replace it with the following to test.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flipcounter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/counter.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
```